# C++: Pass by reference or use private instance variables

Tags: c++, recursion, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, instance-variables

What is the best way of doing this: I got an large collection class `ListCompletions(string digits, Lexicon & lex)` (lex). I need to access it in the `containsPrefix(string prefix)`method. I got the option of passing the lexicon by reference between the methods (of some methods where I do not use it) or I can make a copy of it in `containsPrefix(string prefix)` saving it as a  private instance variable.

My guess is to make a copy of it as a private instance variable would be by far the best option as passing it around within parameters would just further complicate the code, but also, private instance variables are harder to debug since it´s harder to know which methods are using it. But I am asking to be absolutely sure, so I don´t pick up any bad coding habbits.

```
#include "CellPhoneMindReading.h"

void CellPhoneMindReading :: ListCompletions(string digits, Lexicon & lex)
{
    //cout << lex.contains("fedora") << endl;

    RecursiveMnemonics("", "72");
}



/*
 * Function: containsPrefix
 * Usage: containsPrefix(prefix);
 * ----------------------------------------
 * This function returns the given prefix passed as argument if it
 * is found in the Lexicon database. prefixes that are not found
 * is discarded and the return value is a empty string.
 */
string CellPhoneMindReading :: containsPrefix(string prefix)
{
    if (
    return "";
}



/*
 * Function: RecursiveMnemonics
 * Usage: RecursiveMnemonics(prefix, rest);
 * ----------------------------------------
 * This function does all of the real work for ListMnemonics and
 * implements a more general problem with a recursive solution
 * that is easier to see. The call to RecursiveMnemonics generates
 * all mnemonics for the digits in the string rest prefixed by the
 * mnemonic string in prefix. As the recursion proceeds, the rest
 * string gets shorter and the prefix string gets longer.
 */
void CellPhoneMindReading :: RecursiveMnemonics(string prefix, string rest)
{
    if (rest.length() == 0)
    {
        cout << prefix << endl;
        containsPrefix(prefix);
    }
    else {
        string options = DigitLetters(rest[0]);
        for (int i = 0; i < options.length(); i++)
        {
            RecursiveMnemonics(prefix + options[i], rest.substr(1));
        }
    }
}



/*
 * Function: DigitLetters
 * Usage: digits = DigitLetters(ch);
 * ---------------------------------
 * This function returns a string consisting of the legal
 * substitutions for a given digit character. Note that 0 and
 * 1 are handled just by leaving that digit in its position.
 */
string CellPhoneMindReading :: DigitLetters(char ch)
{
    switch (ch) {
        case '0': return ("0");
        case '1': return ("1");
        case '2': return ("ABC");
        case '3': return ("DEF");
        case '4': return ("GHI");
        case '5': return ("JKL");
        case '6': return ("MNO");
        case '7': return ("PRS");
        case '8': return ("TUV");
        case '9': return ("WXY");
        default: cout << "Illegal digit" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a question better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you just store an argument passed to a method of a class to access it during the method call, I'd say it's a code smell, i.e. an indication that something is off.

A member variable on a class defines its state, and in this case the Lexicon doesn't seem to belong to the state of the class since it's just used during the single function call (from the outside perspective), and not used by the class afterwards.

Therefore of the 2 options you gave I would clearly prefer passing the argument along.

A third option would be to add the reference as a constructor argument.

A fourth option would be to have a new class that contains 'RecursiveMnemonics', 'DigitLetters' and 'containsPrefix', and have that new class take the reference to Lexicon as a constructor argument. The new class is then created on the stack by 'ListCompletions'.

Comment: Good answer, but it raises another question.  If the reference is added as a constructor argument, what happens if the referent dies?  More precisely, suppose a `ListCompletions` object `lc`, and further suppose that another object `x` of some other type is constructed using a reference to `lc`.  What happens if `lc` dies before `x` does?

Comment: Not sure if it was a rethorical question or not. The official answer is "undefined behaviour". It will either lead to an immediate crash, or countless hours of the developer spent chasing a "Heisen-bug".
The rules for storing a reference as a member are basically the same as those for storing a pointer, except that it can't be null therefore it is a way to show the user that lifetime of the object is controlled somewhere else.

Comment: @thb: If you're passing references in to the constructor of your class, you are in effect promising by design that the reference will remain valid for the lifetime of the class. If it doesn't then that's a design smell.

Comment: The replies by @carleeto and the answerer are appreciated.  My question was not rhetorical, incidentally, though maybe it should have been.  Years ago, when first learning C++, I experimented with reference members, but never found any application of them that did not seem better served by a pointer member.  Today therefore, I was fishing for an answer of this kind:  "A reference is better than a pointer in this case because...."  I was just wondering what you would say, thinking that maybe I might learn something new from it.  That's all.

Comment: Reference will always point to the same object during it's lifetime, while a pointer can change who it points to. A reference will always point to an object while a pointer doesn't have to. If you can use either a reference member or a pointer you should prefer the reference, which is more restrictive. Another alternative to consider is std::unique_ptr in C++11, which tells the user that the the recipient of the pointer is responsible for lifetime management. To summarize, use the type (pointer, reference, unique_ptr) to convey information about lifetime management.

Comment: @thb: A reference is better than a pointer because you don't need to check all over the place if its not NULL before using it. You assume it is valid. This is also where the implied design promise comes from - the promise that whoever constructed your object and provided a reference to the constructor must in turn guarantee that the object being referred to is valid for the lifetime of your class. In other words, if a reference passed into your constructor is not valid when your class tries to use it, it's typically not your class' fault.

Answer (score 2):

Two comments here.

1. Make sure the Lexicon reference is const. Anything else I think would seem suspicious.
2. Your instinct is right - it's preferable to pass around the Lexicon as argument over using storing it in a private member. However, if all that argument passing gets too much, member instance can be an option. Only you can select the best tradeoff there.

Bonus comment: Why make DigitLetters member function? It does not reference any member data - thus, it would be better as free function.

Comment: Bonus comment: making it a (private, static) method does help the linker. Even better for the linker would be a free standing function in an anonymous namespace, as long as we're in the .cpp file.